# Add Authentication to /swagger/ui/index page - Swagger | Web API | Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm working on a Swagger (Web API) project.
When I first run the application it shows the Login page for Swagger UI.
 So, a user first has to login to access Swagger UI Page, However, if user directly enters "http://example.com/swagger/ui/index" then he's able to access the Swagger UI page.

afaik the swagger-ui is served by the swashbuckle assembly. The source is not available in my project.

How can I make the user redirect to login page if he's not logged in to Swagger UI page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally, I solved it with `DelegtingHandler`, here's how I did it:
Create a file `SwaggerAccessMessageHandler.cs` and add it in `App_Start` folder.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class SwaggerAccessMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (IsSwagger(request) && !Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
            // Redirect to login URL
            string uri = string.Format("{0}://{1}", request.RequestUri.Scheme, request.RequestUri.Authority);    
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private bool IsSwagger(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.Contains("/swagger");
    }
}
```

Next, Wire up the handler in `SwaggeConfig.cs` just before enabling Swagger as follows:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new SwaggerAccessMessageHandler());

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    ...
});
```

Comment: The page isn’t redirecting properly

Comment: What about for ASP.Net core? Which folder should I put in SwaggerAccessMessageHandler.cs file?

Comment: @superninja did you find any solution? as i need same for asp.net core api

Answer (score -1):

[spring-security login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fRu7.png)

in my case, that is not swagger page but spring-security login page.
boot version 2.X includes security auto configuration, so if you add spring-security plugin in build.gradle, remove and restart.