# How to secure Swagger API UI allow only to a authorize user using ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, swagger-ui

I'm working on Web API, currently, I just want to learn about Swagger API how's it good in documentation unit test. I found this to a reference online. Can you help me how to secure Swagger API UI from accessing by an anonymous user or public user? Just designated to an authorized user only.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295887/add-authentication-to-swagger-ui-index-page-swagger-web-api-swashbuckle?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can add an global authentication filter so that all requests will go through that filter.When you need to exclude any controller you can use `[AllowAnonymous]`.

Restricting all and excluding only needed is one of the best practice in the industry.

If you are using ASP.Net Web Api

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute());

    // Other configuration code not shown...
}
```

You can read more about it from [this link of Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters)

If you are using ASP.Net Core you may need to create a middleware. According to  [Asp.Net Core Documentation about Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

> Middleware is software that is assembled into an application pipeline to handle requests and responses. Each component:+
>   Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the pipeline.
>   Can perform work before and after the next component in the pipeline is invoked.

In the middleware check whether the user is authenticated if so proceed with `next();` if not authenticated issue an `Authentication.ChallengeAsync();`

Add the middleware after useAuthenticaion but before useSwagger in the pipeline.

Comment: nice answer for web APIs! but I want to tell if someone is not authorized to access the Swagger UI it will redirect to 404 or unauthorized access page. thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can host the SwaggerUI as a separate instance in IIS and apply appropriate Authorization policy through IIS.